# UDP sockect about string in UWP

Tags: string, sockets, unity-game-engine, uwp

I find a strange problem when I write code in UWP.

I use UDP sockect to send a coordinates to hololens.

The coordinate is like "1.0_1.0_1.0", it was send as string and will be cut according to "_",then the coordinate will be used to control the moving of a sphere.

First of all, it run all right in the unity editor.

But in the hololens, for example, I only receive "1.0_1.0_1.0", but cannot change it to vector3:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using HoloToolkit.Unity;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using Windows.Foundation;
#endif

public class pre : MonoBehaviour
{


public TextMesh tm = null;
public TextMesh tmmm = null;
public GameObject sphere;
string test;
public void ResponseToUDPPacket(string incomingIP, string incomingPort, string data)
{
    string[] centre = data.Split('_');
    float[] num= new float[3];
    if (tm != null)
          tm.text = data;


    num[0] = float.Parse(centre[0]);
    num[1] = float.Parse(centre[1]);
    num[2] = float.Parse(centre[2]);
    Debug.Log(num[1]);

    if (tmmm != null)
        tmmm.text = num[1].ToString();
    sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(num[0], num[1], num[2]);
    //var headPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
   //headPosition.z = headPosition.z+10;
    //sphere1.transform.position = headPosition;
}
}
```

I use two testmesh to show the result, "data"is the string I have received, the first "tm" doesn't have problem.for example, it will show"1.0_1.0_1.0".

But the "tmm" which is get according to num[1] is never work.

I have thought it is the problem of UWP.

BUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I send the UDP string by a c++ program, but when I use a software(UDPsender or something like it) to send string manually, the problem in hololens disappeared!

But I don't think there is a problem in my C++ program, because at least it run well in unity editor.

Is there anyone has idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your emulator and your device have different cultures and one understands 1.0 while the other expects 1,0 in the float.Parse.

You can pass your culture (or InvariantCulture) to float.Parse if that is the case.

Does the Debug.Log(num[1]) print the correct number in all cases? If not, this could confirm the above theory.